# Question about composition of functions to determine a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I'm a little confused about the notation here. I've proven some indentities using this $M(g\circ f)=M(f)M(g)$ but I'm not sure how to go about and proof this one. Any help?

If $A\in M_{n,m}(K)$ y $B\in M_{m,p}(K)$ proof that:

$F_{AB}=F_{A}F_{B}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X\in M_{a\times b}(K)$ we define $F_X:\Bbb R^b\to \Bbb R^a$ by the formula $F_X(\vec{v})=X\vec{v}$.

So, any two matrices $A\in M_{n\times m}(K)$ and $B\in M_{m\times p}(K)$ define a diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\Bbb R^p &\xrightarrow{F_B}&\Bbb R^m \\
         _{F_{AB}}&\searrow&\downarrow_{F_A} \\
&&\Bbb R^n
\end{array}
$$
since $AB$ is an $m\times p$ matrix. We wish to show that this diagram "commutes" in the sense that $F_A\circ F_B=F_{AB}$. To do so, note that every $\vec{v}\in \Bbb R^p$ satisfies
$$
(F_A\circ F_B)(\vec{v})
= F_A(F_B(\vec{v}))
= F_A(B\vec{v})
= A(B\vec{v})
= (AB)\vec{v}
= F_{AB}(\vec{v})
$$
This proves that $F_A\circ F_B=F_{AB}$ as desired.

Comment: Brian thanks. I have a question about the formula you used at the begining: Is there another notation? Because I think I'm interpreting it wrongly, I'm thinking that $X$ is an scalar and that's why after the equal ends up like that.